# Kendo UI for ASP.NET Core MVC kendoDatePicker error

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik-mvc

I was following the Telerik tutorial:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-6/getting-started

When using a DatePicker, I get the error

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoDatePicker'

These are the scripts I am using in the Development environment as per the Telerik tutorial:

```
    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.js"></script>
```

I have jQuery reference above these scripts.

Note: I've upgraded to ASP.NET Core 1.0 and am using Telerik's latest Kendo.Mvc DLL (2016.2.630-Preview) via nuget.

In bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "kendo-ui": "https://bower.telerik.com/bower-kendo-ui.git#~2016.2.630",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive": "git://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive.git#~3.2.4",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
  },
```

In project.json:

```
"Kendo.Mvc": "2016.2.630-Preview"
```

If I simply change the reference to the CDN Production Environment scripts:

```
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

my kendoDatePicker works.

are the newer scripts missing kendoDatePicker?

Comment: I would guess that one of your scripts is not loading correctly in your development environment.  You can use developer console in whatever browser you are using to see if there is a 404 where kendo.all.js or kendo.aspnetmvc.js are not loading.  Is there a console error?

Comment: You are correct. The reference has changed to the scripts. Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core. Use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] and/or [tag:asp.net-core] tags instead

Comment: Seano666 will you post an "answer" so I can vote for it